# Im trying to open a command line from c# windows application in order to run an exe file but its only opening the cmd and not running the command

Tags: c#, cmd

This is the code i'm trying to open the command line with. What i want to do is to run the command `"client_server.exe " + received_ip; in the cmd but its only opening the window and not running the command. does anyone have a solution for me?

```
var process = new Process();
                    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    //startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                    startInfo.Arguments = @"client_server.exe " + received_ip;
                    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    process.Start();

                    process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: You could run `cmd /?` manually first to see *what arguments and switches cmd accepts*, or look it up online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried the `UseShellExecute` property?

```
var process = new Process();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.FileName = "client_server.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = received_ip;

startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

process.WaitForExit();
```